# Parse XML to PHP using ID value

Tags: php, arrays, xml

How can I echo xml values with php by calling their "columnId" and not the position in the array ? (The array is really long)

Here is a sample of the xml :

```
<Data>
   <Value columnId="ITEMS_SOLD">68</Value>
   <Value columnId="TOTAL_SALES">682</Value>
   <Value columnId="SHIPPING_READY">29</Value>
   ...
</Data>
```

The following php gives me all of the values :

```
$url = 'XXX';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($feed->Data->Value as $key => $value){
   echo $value; 
}
```

I would like to be able to use something like that in my document :

```
echo $feed->Data->Value['TOTAL_SALES'];
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $feed->Data->Value[1];
```

Comment: That is basically what i have so far but i'm trying to avoid the pain to count in the giant array; Plus it would be easy to code by using columnIds instead of counting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have an another way for your solution. You can convert *xml object* into array and use this for further process. Try this code:

```
<?php

$url = 'XXX';
//Read xml data, If file exist...
if (file_exists($url)) {

        //Load xml file...
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        $arrColumn = array();//Variable initialization...
    $arrFromObj = (array) $xml;//Convert object to array...
    $i = 0;//Variable initialization with value...

    //Loop until data...
    foreach($xml AS $arrKey => $arrData)    {
        $columnId = (string) $arrData['columnId'][0];//array object to string...
        $arrColumn[$columnId] = $arrFromObj['Value'][$i];//assign data to array...
        $i++;//Incremental variable...
    }

} else {//Condition if file not exist and display message...
    exit('Failed to open file');
}

?>
```

Above code will store result into array variable `$arrColumn` and result is:

```
Array
(
    [ITEMS_SOLD] => 68
    [TOTAL_SALES] => 682
    [SHIPPING_READY] => 29
)
```

Hope this help you well!

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath. SimpleXML and DOM support it, but SimpleXML has some limits (It can only fetch node lists).

#### SimpleXML

```
$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);

var_dump(
  (string)$feed->xpath('//Value[@columnId = "TOTAL_SALES"]')[0]
);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "682"
```

#### DOM

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//Value[@columnId = "TOTAL_SALES"])')
);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "682"
```